# C++ время выполнения обычной и inline-функции, сравнение

Tags: c++, функции, оптимизация, время, inline

Имею вот такую простую программу:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 100

using namespace std;

float func(float x)
{
    return x*x*log(x)/((1+x)*(1+x));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int a, b;
    float h, x, result;

    cout << "Введите границы интеграла: ";
    cin >> a >> b;
    h = ((float)b - a) / N;
    x = (float)a;

    //Формула трапеций
    result = func((float)a) / 2 + func((float)b) / 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        result += func(x + h * i);
    cout << "Результат по формуле трапеций: " << result * h;

    //Формула Симпсона
    result = func((float)a) + func((float)b) + 4*func(a+h);
    for (int i = 2; i < N; i += 2)
        result += 2 * func(a + h * i) + 4 * func(a + h * (i + 1));
    cout << "\nРезультат по формуле Симпсона: " << result * h / 3;

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Считает определенный интеграл заданной в методе func(float x) функции в заданных границах. Стало интересно, как поведет себя программа, если func сделать inline. Для наглядности делал цикл

```
for (int i=0; i<10000000;i++) func(i);
```

и замерял время библиотекой time.h, функцией clock.
Результат - около 2000мс inline вариант, около 1800 обычный.
Собственно вопрос - почему так? Разве не должна inline-функция небольших размеров показывать бОльшую производительность?

UPD: компилятор VS2017 с дефолтными настройками. На какие именно параметры стоит обратить внимание?

Comment: Для начала убедитесь, что вы меряли результат с оптимизацией. Функция практически наверняка бы встроилась (или не встроилась) независимо от inline. А `for (int i=0; i<10000000;i++) func(i);` могло быть выкинуто из-за отсутствия в цикле побочных эффектов.

Comment: Почему в вопросе отсутствует информация об компиляторе и настройках компиляции? Без всего этого вопрос не имеет никакого смысла. (В 4 случаях из 5 оказывается, что авторы таких вопросов замеряли время выполнения в отладочной конфигурации кода (!).)

Comment: современные компиляторы выполняют встраивание несложных функций.  Маленькую разницу по времени вы можете наблюдать  даже при одинаковом коде, так как операционная система работает

Comment: Также для pure функции `func` компилятор просто выкинет нафиг ваш цикл `for (int i=0; i<10000000;i++) func(i);`, ибо результат работы функции вы просто игнорируете. Так что что вы там такое меряли - не ясно.

Comment: Замеры проводил несколько раз для каждого варианта, только один раз из ~5 для каждого варианта inline показал равную (даже не бОльшую) производительность, в остальных случаях - проиграл. Да и 200 мс не такое маленькое время.

Comment: Что такое "дефлотные настроки" VS2017? Какая конфигурация была выбрана? Debug или Release?

Comment: @AnT ```start = clock(); цикл; end = clock(); cout << end - start;``` Дебаг. 2 секунды выполнения не похожи на то, что компилятор выкинул цикл, тут, мне кажется, Вы не правы.

Comment: Еще раз: ваш цикл не имеет побочных эффектов и не имеет наблюдаемого поведения. Любой уважающий компилятор выкинет его вообще. Мерить его бессмысленно. Если ваш компилятор его не выкинул, значит вы мерили отладочную версию кода - это еще более бессмысленно.

Comment: Посмотрите реальный ассемблерный код для начала. Ключик `/FAs` компилятора.

Comment: *"Дебаг."* - ну вот и ответ...

Comment: **Дебаг**??? Ну то есть вы страдали бессмысленой фигней. Нет никакого смысла тестировать производительность отладочной версии кода. Производительность "дебаг" версии кода ничего не значит и логике вроде "inline функции должны быть быстрее" она не подчиняется. А в релизной версии кода ваш цикл будет просто выброшен из кода целиком.

Comment: Хорошо, допустим я не буду использовать бессмысленный цикл, а просто поставлю N 10.000.000, тогда итераций будет еще больше, но они не будут бессмысленны, т.к. значение, полученное в цикле, используется далее. Как тогда будет?

Comment: Не понял. Покажите, как у вас "значение, полученное в цикле, используется далее"? Вам нужно заставить компилятор честно сгенерировать все итерации цикла. И тестировать релиз (оптимизированную) версию кода.

Comment: Не в псевдоцикле, а в программе в шапке. Сделать #define N 10.000.000, тогда циклы рассчета интегралов будут осмысленные

Comment: Прекрасно. Можете сделать так. Но тестировать надо именно release версию кода, а не "дебаг". И, заверяю вас, в release версии кода, компилятор скорее всего будет инлайнить вашу функцию `func` независимо от того, напишете ли вы явное `inline` или нет.

Comment: Действительно, в релизе компилятор даже сказал, когда я убрал inline у функции: 1 functions had inline decision re-evaluated but remain unchanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой код -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

float func(float x)
{
    return x*x*log(x)/((1+x)*(1+x));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i=0; i<10000000;i++) func(i);
    clock_t stop = clock();
    cout << (stop-start) << endl;
}
```

вылетает при нормальных условиях компиляции с оптимизацией мгновенно.

Что и не удивительно: вот во что он компилируется:

```
main    PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 13   : {

$LN13:
    push    rbx
    sub rsp, 32                 ; 00000020H

; 14   :     clock_t start = clock();

    call    clock
    mov ebx, eax

; 15   :     for (int i=0; i<10000000;i++) func(i);
; 16   :     clock_t stop = clock();

    call    clock

; 17   :     cout << (stop-start) << endl;

    sub eax, ebx
    lea rcx, OFFSET FLAT:?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A ; std::cout
    mov edx, eax
    call    ??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEAAAEAV01@J@Z ; std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<
; File c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\ostream

; 206  :        return ((*_Pfn)(*this));

    mov rcx, rax
    call    ??$endl@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@@Z ; std::endl<char,std::char_traits<char> >
; File g:\tmp\test\test.cpp

; 18   : }

    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 32                 ; 00000020H
    pop rbx
    ret 0
main    ENDP
```

Т.е. его просто **нет**.

В отладочной версии и с `inline`, и без оного - результат один:

```
; 15   :     for (int i=0; i<10000000;i++) func(i);

    mov DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN4@main
$LN2@main:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR i$1[rsp]
    inc eax
    mov DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], eax
$LN4@main:
    cmp DWORD PTR i$1[rsp], 10000000        ; 00989680H
    jge SHORT $LN3@main
    cvtsi2ss xmm0, DWORD PTR i$1[rsp]
    call    ?func@@YAMM@Z               ; func
    jmp SHORT $LN2@main
$LN3@main:
```

Разницу в 200 мс у себя можете спокойно отнести к погрешности измерений :) - их надо делать для хоть какой-то точности раз 20-30-40, усреднять и оценивать погрешность...

А главное - `inline`, как и марксизм :), не догма, а руководство к действию. Компилятор **сам** решит, обращать на это слово внимание или нет. Да, его можно заставить нестандартными расширениями сделать этот `inline`, но в общем случае компилятору - виднее..

P.S. В коде

```
inline float func(float x)
{
    return x*x*log(x)/((1+x)*(1+x));
}

float funs(float x)
{
    return x*x*log(x)/((1+x)*(1+x));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    {
        double z = 0;
        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int i=1; i<100000000;i++) z += func(i);
        clock_t stop = clock();
        cout << (stop-start) << endl;
        cout << z << endl;
    }
    {
        double z = 0;
        clock_t start = clock();
        for (int i=1; i<100000000;i++) z += funs(i);
        clock_t stop = clock();
        cout << (stop-start) << endl;
        cout << z << endl;
    }
}
```

компилятор благополучно заинлайнил оба вызова.

По 40 тестам время первого цикла 568±12 тактов, второго - 569±14. Так что в пределах погрешности все OK. Вы у себя погрешность оценивали?